# 3 entities execute the same lambda predicate. How creating one lambda expression generic for these entities

Tags: asp.net-mvc-2, entity-framework-4, lambda, repository-pattern

I Have 3 entities.
**Product**
LangID
ProductName

**Category**
LangID 
CatName 

**ProductType**
LangID
TypeName

As you can see, each of them has LangID Property.
I Would like be able to create a generic repository that will contain only one function that will return an `Func<T, bool> GetLmbLang()`

```
   public interface IBaseRepository<T> where T : class
   {
        Func<T, bool> GetLmbLang();
   }

   public class BaseRepository<T> : IBaseRepository<T> where T : class
   {

      public Func<T, bool> GetLmbLang()
      {
          //ERROR HERE
          //That dosen't work here
          return (p => p.LangID == 1);
      }
   }
```

Someone has an idea ???.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way you can accomplish this is by creating an interface with the LangID property, and have each of your classes implement this.

```
public interface IHasLangID
{
  string LangID { get; set; }
}

public class Product : IHasLangID
...
public class Category : IHasLangID
...
public class ProductType : IHasLangID
...

public interface IBaseRepository<T> where T : IHasLangID
...
public class BaseRepository<T> : IBaseRepository<T> where T : IHasLangID
```

Comment: @Jean Same place as you had put it I suppose, inside BaseRepository<T>.